# XCode find with regex incorrectly returning no results

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode

I'm trying to run a search within XCode (to find blocks that contain a reference to `self` though this is not important) however the search is not finding any matches. When I use the same regex expression on various online debuggers or programmatically using `NSRegularExpression` I get the results I expect. I understand xCode uses the ICU engine, however the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSRegularExpression states that the ICU syntax is also used.

The expression I am using is as follows (I know its not perfect but it seems to work so far!):

```
\^\(*[a-zA-z\*\,\s]*\)*[\s]*\{[a-zA-Z0-9:;\[\]\s\=\_\.\/\-@"\!\*\(\)\,]+self
```

or escaped:

```
NSString * expression = @"\\^\\(*[a-zA-z\\*\\,\\s]*\\)*[\\s]*\\{[a-zA-Z0-9:;\\[\\]\\s\\=\\_\\.\\/\\-@\"\\!\\*\\(\\)\\,]+self";
```

Debuggex provides a nice way to visualise the expression and also a test match here [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/udISkwE-E18zg5Ll):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Has any one else come across any quirks with the XCode implementation that might cause false negatives?

Thanks

Comment: A few comments to begin: **1** special characters inside character classes are not the same as in the rest of the regex, you can boil it down to `\^\(*[a-zA-z*,\s]*\)*[\s]*\{[a-zA-Z0-9:;\[\]\s=_./@"!*(),-]+self` (`\^` is a literal `^`, not beginning of string) **2** The point of putting `@` in front of your string is *precisely* not to have to double escape.

Comment: Ah, I was perhaps a little over zealous with the escaped characters, but unfortunately the issue remains. (The double escapes are to prevent XCode throwing up compiler warnings)